# Observable inside observable and merge results into the others

Tags: angular, xsd, rxjs, observable, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I´m trying to merge multiple observables together. In general i am trying to request an xsd file using angular httpClient and parse it using xml2js library. the problem is that this xsd file contains import statements which reference external files.

So what i am trying to do is the following:

1. request main xsd file
2. parse main xsd file (rxjs map operator)
3. process all import statements within that file
4. recursive all of 1. for each import (use a forkJoin operator to merge those)
5. merge parsed imports with parsed main xsd file

   ```
   this.http.get('<PATH to main xsd>')
     .pipe(map(data => {
       xml2js.parseString(data, (err, xmlObject) => {
         if (err) {
           console.error('ERROR', err);
         } else {
         data = xmlObject;
         }
       });
       return data;
     }))
     .pipe(mergeMap((data) => {
       if (xmlObject.xs_schema.xs_import !== undefined) {
         const requests: Observable<any>[] = [];
         for (const xmlImport of xmlObject.xs_schema.xs_import) {
           const path = 'xmlImport.path';
           requests.push(this.getXsdSchema(path));
         }
         return forkJoin(requests);
       } else {
         return empty();
       }
     }));
   ```

The code above works until the pipe with mergeMap is executed for one of the imported files. I think returning an empty observable if there are not imports in the file might be a problem.
So far i was not able to figure out how i can include the imports in my main xsd object.

I tried to make up a demo to show the current state and the problem:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x26paa

Comment: It doesn't work how? Ideally, can you make a demo?

Comment: i will try to make a demo

Comment: i added a demo (view here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x26paa). the main.xsd file contains two import statements. I would expect that a request will be generated for both of them but only the first obe gets executed and logged to the console.

Comment: Hi but _data_ is an Observable?

Comment: I see both `sub1.xsd` and `sub2.xsd` called.

Comment: If i look at the console just the way it is right now i see only main.xsd and sub1.xsd printed. How do you know that sub2.xsd gets called as well.

Comment: @ALGDB are you referring to data in line 48 in the stackblitz?

Comment: Yes the line 48, and also the parseString function return what?

Comment: @ALGDB parseString returns actually nothing, but i extract an object from the callback. Data in line 41 is the xmlObject.

Comment: @ALGDB Data in line 48 is no observable

Comment: I can see it in Chrome Dev Tools

Comment: @martin can only see the following in the dev tools:  
  
_log of main.xsd (xml String)  
log of main.xsd (Object)  
log of sub1.xsd (xml String)_  
-- END  
  
Thats ist. No logging of sub2.xsd as far as i understand.